# How to get the view from an activity/class from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i have a table layout, in each row i have a setOnTouchListener with a class that allows me to detect swiping in rows, it already detects that, but what i'm trying to do is that when the person swaps the row, the row is removed, i have tried several things but i think i need to get the view in the other class in order to get the row index.
I have the instance of my Swipe Class global as:

```
ActivitySwipeDetector activitySwipeDetector = new ActivitySwipeDetector(this);
```

Whenever i create a row i just add:             `tr.setOnTouchListener(activitySwipeDetector);`
tr being the row
And this the ActivitySwipeDetector, the commented part is what i was trying to do:

```
public class ActivitySwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

    static final String logTag = "ActivitySwipeDetector";
    private Activity activity;
    static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    Invoices invoices = new Invoices();
    NavManager nav = new NavManager();

    public ActivitySwipeDetector(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void onRightSwipe(){
        System.out.println("Swiped Correctly from Right to Left");
        int index = (int)nav.getCurrentFocus().getTag();
        invoices.data.remove(index);
        System.out.println("Eliminado Correctamente");
    }

    public void onLeftSwipe(){
    }

    public void onDownSwipe(){
    }

    public void onUpSwipe(){
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // swipe horizontal?
                if(Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY))
                {
                    if(Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                        // left or right
                        if(deltaX > 0) { this.onRightSwipe(); return true; }
                        if(deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.i(logTag, "Horizontal Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                        return false; // We don't consume the event
                    }
                }
                // swipe vertical?
                else
                {
                    if(Math.abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE){
                        // top or down
                        if(deltaY < 0) { this.onDownSwipe(); return true; }
                        if(deltaY > 0) { this.onUpSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.i(logTag, "Vertical Swipe was only " + Math.abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE);
                        return false; // We don't consume the event
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance, i would really appreciate at least some ideas on what to do!
*Edit: The Table is filled by data: an ArrayList

Comment: Swap or swipe rows?

Comment: Swipe* sorry typo

Comment: Most likely swipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a listener:

```
public interface SwipeCallback {
    void onRightSwipe();
    void onLeftSwipe();
    void onDownSwipe();
    void onUpSwipe();
}
```

Add that listener to your constructor and set it to a global variable:

```
private SwipeCallback swipeCallback;

public ActivitySwipeDetector(Activity activity, SwipeCallback callback) {
    this.activity = activity;
    swipeCallback = callback;
}
```

Then call the listener's methods in the corresponding methods:

```
public void onRightSwipe() {
    listener.onRightSwipe();
    //...
}

//etc
```

When you construct the detector:

```
ActivitySwipeDetector activitySwipeDetector = new ActivitySwipeDetector(
        this,
        new SwipeCallback() {
            //handle the swipes
            @Override
            public void onRightSwipe() {}

            @Override
            public void onLeftSwipe() {}

            @Override
            public void onUpSwipe() {}

            @Override
            public void onDownSwipe() {}
        }
);
```

Comment: The last one is supposed to be where i'm supposed to call it in the other class right?

Comment: Yes, wherever you're creating the instance of ActivitySwipeDetector.

Comment: Thanks, i was having a lot of trouble with that!. love you